# Virtualbox on Linux without windows manager and win 7 as guest

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

is there a possibility for having a host system without gui (e.g. ubuntu server) and have a windows 7 guest fully working? The guest system should not be working in headless mode, I need a full windows 7 as guest.

I ve a feeling, that you need some window-manager for this, is that right?

**Edit**

- I would like to have a linux as Host and a win7 as guest (with virtualbox)

### What I've don so far

- Installed Linux Mint as Host
- Installed VirtualBox
- Imported the Win7 vm

#### First Scenario

When I start cinnamon and open a shell and type `vboxmanage startvm win7` everything works fine

#### Second Scenario

When I switch to tty2 and write `vboxmanage startvm win7`
it says

```sh
VboxManage: error: The virtual machine 'win7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 6
VboxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

#### Third Scenario

When I'm on tty2 and I do `export DISPLAY=:0` and start the vm via `vboxmanage startvm win7` then

```sh
Waiting for VM "win7" to power on...
```

with a blinking cursor

When I now press alt+ctrl+F7 for switching to tty7 the vm starts like a charm.

Has anyone an idea what I can do to get it working without switching ttyx?

Comment: Why not assign the graphics card to the VM, so Linux won't see it, but Windows does? You can access the host over SSH

Comment: so it is possible? But I don`t understand why I have to do this? I would access the host via keyboard, I just mentioned ubuntu server as a possiblity, cuz I dont want to install gnome or xfce or something similar...

Comment: If you graphics card is assigned to the VM, then there will be no output on the screen from the server, so the keyboard is worthless. You can use PuTTY to SSH into the host from the Windows VM

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but why shall I assign it to the VM in the first place? This is what I dont understand.

Comment: In fact it's not possible for me to connect to the host system. My favorite would be:

Linux starting, then login, then vboxmanage startvm Win7

if I do that I get

`virtualbox terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 6 `

Comment: The graphics card can be used either by the VM or by the host, but not by both at the same time. If you assign it to the host, then the VM wil use a graphiscs card emulation, tht is very, very slow and has no really usable 3D acceleration (only rudimentary).